# OK to use <wikiname> namespace for other purposes? (mediawiki)

Tags: mediawiki

I'm creating a wiki where users edit content in one namespace, and the 
"results" are displayed in the Main namespace.

I'd prefer to create no new namespaces.

Is it safe to use the "Barry Carter's Wiki" namespace (ie, the wiki's 
name namespace) for my 'edit content' namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of pages in the wikiname namespace (the canonic name for it is Project namespace, by the way) which will get linked from various places; e. g. Project:Copyright will be linked from the copyright notice on the bottom of the screen. If you are not bothered by that, I don't see any problems. (You should check out the [FlaggedRevs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlaggedRevs) extension, though.)

Comment: Thanks! The FlaggedRevs extension doesn't seem to do what I want, but I may be missing something.

Comment: It allows users to edit the main namespace, but the changes only appear after accepted by someone who has the right to do so. I speculated that you want to use the secondary namespace for some sort of review procedure.

Comment: Ah, no. I'm actually parsing whats written in the 2ndary namespace to create pages in primary namespace. See https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/sample-data/anno1.txt and https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/meta-mediawiki.pl for more.